# list to bind variable in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function that gets a list of elements and puts them into a table, in this way a list can be used as a bind variable. Everything works OK, except when I give as an element in the list `USER`, it seems that Sql Developer does some parsing and leads to some `ORA-20001: comma-separated list invalid near T,USE` error. Do you know if it's possible to add a workaround for this so the function will work also with `USER` element?

The function:

```
  FUNCTION comma_to_table(iv_raw IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN bind_tab_typ
  PIPELINED
  IS
     ltab_lname dbms_utility.lname_array;
     ln_len     BINARY_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
     dbms_utility.comma_to_table(list   => iv_raw
                                ,tablen => ln_len
                                ,tab    => ltab_lname);
     FOR i IN 1 .. ln_len LOOP
        PIPE ROW (ltab_lname(i));
     END LOOP;
  END comma_to_table;
```

And here is the query to test it:

```
select * from table(ui_util.comma_to_table(:myList))
```

if for myList I put `TEST,SUPPORT,USERT` it works perfecly. If I change it to `TEST,SUPPORT,USER` I get the error mentioned above. Any suggestion?

Comment: what type is the return 'bind_tab_typ'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the [`dbms_utility.comma_to_table` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/doc/timesten.1122/e21645/d_util.htm#i1002468) requires the elements of the list to be valid Oracle identifiers, though that isn't made clear in the docs really. [This AskTom article](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1415803954123) refers to it though, via the underlying [`name_tokenize` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/doc/timesten.1122/e21645/d_util.htm#BJEFIFBJ):

> Note that you do not  have to use REAL object names (these tables and
>   procedures do not have to exist) but you must use VALID object
>   identifiers.  If you do not use a valid object identifier,
>   NAME_TOKENIZE will raise an error.

It isn't to do with the binding or SQL Developer, it's a database restriction.

You can see the same kind of error if you call the `dbms_utility.comma_to_table` procedure directly:

```
declare
  arr dbms_utility.uncl_array;
  len binary_integer;
begin
  dbms_utility.comma_to_table('USER', len, arr);
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-20001: comma-separated list invalid near R
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 236
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 256
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Or by calling `dbms_utility.name_tokenize` directly:

```
declare
  a varchar2(30);
  b varchar2(30);
  c varchar2(30);
  d varchar2(30);
  e binary_integer;
begin
  dbms_utility.name_tokenize('USER', a, b, c, d, e);
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-00931: missing identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 167
ORA-06512: at line 8
00931. 00000 -  "missing identifier"
```

You can't use this if your comma-separated values are [reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10830/appb.htm#BABGHAFH) or aren't allowed as identifiers for some other reason; starting with a number, for example. You'd get the same issue if the list contained `TABLE` or `42TAB`. This isn't really what it is intended for, as Tom mentions.

You can partially get around the restrictions by forcing all the elements to be double-quoted, which you could do with a `replace`. and then any of those examples are allowed:

```
declare
  arr dbms_utility.uncl_array;
  len binary_integer;
begin
  dbms_utility.comma_to_table('"USER","TABLE","42TAB"', len, arr);
end;
/

anonymous block completed
```

So for your code, modify `iv_raw` as you pass it across, and then remove the double-quotes from each returned value:

```
FUNCTION comma_to_table(iv_raw IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN bind_tab_typ
  PIPELINED
  IS
     ltab_lname dbms_utility.lname_array;
     ln_len     BINARY_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
     dbms_utility.comma_to_table(list   => '"' || replace(iv_raw, ',', '","') || '"'
                                ,tablen => ln_len
                                ,tab    => ltab_lname);
     FOR i IN 1 .. ln_len LOOP
        PIPE ROW (replace(ltab_lname(i), '"'));
     END LOOP;
  END comma_to_table;
```

Then this works:

```
select * from table(ui_util.comma_to_table('USER,TABLE,42T'));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------
USER
TABLE
42T
```

But you're still restricted to each element being 30 characters or less, since that is a restriction on even quoted identifiers.