# comma to table function error with number values

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I already know comma to table function (The other question is different). But there is a different situation here. I think its an Oracle defect. If there is a solution for my problem, I want to learn.

When I use with varchar values its ok, but when I try to use with number values, getting error like this;

ORA-20001: comma-separated list invalid near 3

```
dbms_utility.comma_to_table('abc,def', l_tablen, l_tab);    OK



dbms_utility.comma_to_table('12,13', l_tablen, l_tab);   NOT OK
```

Error:
ORA-20001: comma-separated list invalid near 3

```
DECLARE
      l_tab   dbms_utility.uncl_array;
      l_tablen   number;
      v_var number;
    BEGIN
      dbms_utility.comma_to_table('1214,1547,1219', l_tablen, l_tab);
      dbms_output.put_line('TABLE LENGTH : '|| l_tablen);
      dbms_output.put_line('TABLE COUNT  : '|| l_tab.COUNT);
      for i in 1..l_tablen
      loop
       dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(i));
     end loop;     
   END;
```

Comment: @Sathya this question is different issue. Thanks. There is not any dot value in my case.

Comment: Maybe because numbers are not fully qualified attribute names

Comment: it's not the dot value that's the problem, but the number values, which are not valid PL/SQL name. Points to the same issue as in linked post.

Comment: Hope [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1415803954123) helps you.

Comment: @Jack Use any one of my four solutions in the linked post. You would not be able to use the in-built dbms_utility package in your case, since it would fail for digits.

Comment: @Jack - you can also force all the elements in the list to appear as valid identifiers [by wrapping them in double qoutes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22787876/266304) - at least as long as they aren't too long to be valid. It's still a bit of a hack though.